# How to calculate gamma coeffcients in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to replicate this paper "Gleditsch, Kristian Skrede and Michael D. Ward. 2006. "Diffusion and the International Context of Democratization", International Organization 50: 911-933" and I have problems finding the gamma coefficients. The base model is a probit:

```
glm(I(baut==1) ~ log(laggdppc) + pnbdem 
  + cwar + ipyears + egr + propdem 
  + I(bautlag) + I(log(laggdppc)*bautlag) 
  + I(pnbdem*bautlag) + I(cwar*bautlag) + I(ipyears*bautlag) 
  + I(egr*bautlag) + I(propdem*bautlag)
  + I(nbtd>0*bautlag),
  model=T,
  family=binomial(link=probit),na.action=na.omit,data=repdata,
  control=glm.control(epsilon=0.0001, maxit=100))
```

The authors suggest that, in order to find the gamma coefficients, I should sum the beta coefficients with the corresponding alpha coefficients (i.e., the interactive terms). I tried to do it with the canned version glm() and family=Gamma, but I get an error because my dependent variable (baut) includes 0s. Is there another command which I can use to calculate the gamma coefficients?
The data can be found [here](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=hdl:1902.1/12710)

Comment: They used a Markov state transition model. Why do you think that was a probit model?

Comment: This model is a probit to me:

Comment: I think you need statistical advice.

Comment: The base model indicated in the replication files is a probit (glm command with family=binomial(link=probit)). And it's understandable because the dependent variable is binary.

Comment: Yes, I seek advice :) It's my first time replicating a paper